# Why expect(Future.value(true), Future.value(true)) has fail result in flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

So I feel a bit confused with this matcher.

Why does this test returning fail?

```
expect(Future.value(true),Future.value(true));
```

I thought it was the same value and the matcher should be returning success for that test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different objects which are compared using the <strike>hashcode</strike> ***operator ==, not by hashCode. However, the default operator == implementation compares object identity.*** Which will be different because they are not the same object.

If you `await` the futures the values will be compared and it will pass.

```dart
  test('test', () async {
    print(Future.value(true).hashCode);
    print(Future.value(true).hashCode);
    expect(await Future.value(true), await Future.value(true));
  });
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html

Edit:
To answer your other question:

> Do you know how to compare 2 same classes? I just try expect(ClassA(), ClassA()) still returning fail test. How to make expect(ClassA(), ClassA()) to pass?

You're kind of using the `expect` in the wrong way. If you want to know if the class is a specific kind you can do this:

```dart
test('test', () async {
    final ClassA classAInstance = ClassA();
    expect(classAInstance, isA<ClassA>());
    expect(classAInstance == classAInstance, true);
  });
```

*Thank you jamesdlin for correcting me on the hashcode.*

Comment: Aaah I see, so when we didn't await Future value, flutter would compare by hashCode.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know how to compare 2 same classes?
I just try expect(ClassA(), ClassA()) 
still returning fail test. How to make expect(ClassA(), ClassA()) to pass?

Comment: Never mind, I can use, `expect(c is ClassA, true)` to compare class names.

Comment: @AfandiYusuf I edited my answer to include your additional question

Comment: @AfandiYusuf Objects are compared by `operator ==`, not by `hashCode`.  However, the default `operator ==` implementation compares object *identity*.

Comment: @jamesdlin aah I see, thanks for your additional answer.